# How can I check if the Operating System is Sun Os or Unix or Solaris from by bashrc

Tags: bash, unix, sunos

I want to know, how can we check in the bashrc file, what operating system is it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `uname -a` in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Or just `uname -s` if you don't need the version number and other information.

Answer (score 6):

There is no portable way to know what Operating System is running.

Depending on the OS, `uname -s` will tell you what **kernel** you are running but not necessarily what **OS**.

Moreover, it cannot be SunOS **or** Unix **or** Solaris. Solaris is all of them: both a Unix compliant OS and an OS based on the SunOS kernel.

One of these might give you a precise answer depending on the Unix or Linux implementation:

```
cat /etc/release # SVR4, Solaris
cat /etc/redhat-release
cat /etc/*elease
cat /etc/lsb-release
oslevel -r # AIX
system_profiler -detailLevel -2 # Mac OS/X
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.4 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.4 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

Comment: And what's that supposed to do? Basile's answer seems to cover this question just fine, so please explain what this code improves compared to Basile's.

Comment: LOL.. whatever.. it's not code btw.. just a more specific answer to a question.

Comment: :)

Thanks user.. 
+1 for the precise answer..

though.. I just wanted the OS name, which was answered earlier by Basile, and it fitted my needs.
Also the answer by jlliagre gave me these information as well.